# VB.NET Static Code Anaylsis

Tags: vb.net, static-analysis

Does anyone know of a good code static code analyser for vb.net?

I've seen plenty for c#, and I think VS 2008 some one built in. But we're currently only using vs 2005...

Answer (score 6):

[FxCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop) does just that.

Specific for VB.NET is [Project Analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Analyzer).

Comment: Project Analyser is a dead link

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are looking for Fortify is another application that analyzes code really well, but it isn't a VB specific, works for all of .net

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) which analysis all .NET code (C#, VB.NET, F#...).
For VB.NET code you'll miss 2 metrics on source code comment and source code cyclomatic complexity (but you still have CC computed from IL code).

See all feature of NDepend here http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx:

 -  Code Query and Rule over LINQ (CQLinq)

 -  Compare Builds

 -  82 code metrics

 -  Manage Complexity and Dependencies

 -  Detect Dependency Cycles

 -  Harness Test Coverage Data

 -  Enforce Immutability and Purity

 -  Warnings about the health of your Build Process

 -  Generate custom report from your Build Process

 -  Diagrams

 -  Facilities to cope with real-world environment