# Enforcing using the class name whenever a shared member is accessed

Tags: vb.net, coding-style

We have a coding standard that says all shared (static) fields and methods must be called with the class name.  E.g.

```
NameOfClass.whatever
```

Rather then

```
whatever
```

Is there a tool that we can use to check this is in fact the case?
(Likewise for modules)

**Sorry I should have make it clearer we are using VB.NET.**

---

This is a bigger example of what I mean.

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Shared Sub SharedMethod()

    End Sub

    Public Shared sharedField As Integer

    Public Sub NotSharedMethod()
        'this next line shold be written as Class1.SharedMethod
        SharedMethod()

        'this next line shold be written as Class1.sharedField
        sharedField = 5
    End Sub

End Class
```

see also [What StyleCop like tools are there for VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131350/what-stylecop-like-tools-are-there-for-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I never did find a good tools for this.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Sure, just create a [custom rule](http://scottwhite.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-custom-stylecop-rules-in-c.html) in [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis). Then incorporate the use of StyleCop into your automated build process.</del>

Sorry, I did not even realize that StyleCop did not have a VB.NET version. What you need is a static analysis tool for VB.NET. Based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342456/vb-net-static-code-anaylsis), it looks like  [Project Analyzer](http://www.aivosto.com/project/project.html) is an option. Unfortunately it's not free.

From the web site:

> Maintain. To help maintenance, Project Analyzer lets you enforce coding standards[.]

Whatever tool you use, be sure it incorporate it into your automated build process.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

Use **[StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis)** and write your custom rule to do your check.

Here's a [reference to check how to write custom-rule](http://scottwhite.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-custom-stylecop-rules-in-c.html) for StyleCop.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a great tool!

Comment: **StyleCop** rocks! StyleCop is basically functional implementation of rules and guidelines described in Framework Design Guidelines [http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613/ref=pd_sim_b_4]. Many .Net core team people have contributed to this book.

Comment: StyleCop sounds great, but the question is tagged VB.net, and StyleCop only supports C# http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=383

Comment: -1 as this would have been a great answer for a C# question, but I was asking about VB.NET

Answer (score 2):

In the Project Properties > Compile, you can set the Warning configuration for "Instance Variable access shared member" to Error and it should generate a compiler error instead of a warning.

I'm not sure how you might do it for all projects.  You could change the project template to include that option for all new projects.

Comment: thanks, this works for access from outside of the class, but not inside the class, see the edit to my question for when it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [FxCop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9aeaa970-f281-4fb0-aba1-d59d7ed09772) for this purpose, and write a custom rule. [Here is a good site that explains how to write custom FxCop rules](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, The problem in that the generated intermediate code is the same in both cases, so the tool needs to run on the vb.net source code.