# What StyleCop like tools are there for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, coding-style, static-analysis

see also [VB.NET Static Code Anaylsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342456/vb-net-static-code-anaylsis)

For better or for worst we now have a **VB.NET** coding standards document that is based on a C# coding standard as enforced by StyleCop.

For example

- the number of spaces you should put in each side of a “+” sign etc
- all instance Members (fields and methods!) must be access as “me.fieldName”
- all shared members must be accessed as “className.fieldName”

As I tend to think:

> If it’s in a requirements document it
>   should be check for by an automatic
>   system

I am looking for (ideally free) tools that will check for that short of rules on VB.NET code, as these are style issues that don’t make it into the compiled output, FxCop is not useful.

(I would personally match rather that we just check for important things like duplicated code and single reasonability for each class (so no more multi thousand line classes!), but as I need to keep to the coding standard document I wish to have a tool to help me do so.)

see also [Enforcing using the class name whenever a shared member is accessed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103579/enforcing-using-the-class-name-whenever-a-shared-member-is-accessed)

**About the bounty.**
I am looking for a list of VB.NET code checking tools, with a short summery of what each tool can do and its limitations.   If the tools are not free, please include some ideal of cost.

---

Does anyone have experience using [CodeRush/Refactor](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/)! or [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) with VB.NET to check for this type of coding style issues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know of no free source code analysis tools with good VB support.  There are, however, at least two commercial tools that may be suitable:

1. [submain CodeIt.Right](http://submain.com/products/codeit.right.aspx)
2. [SSW Code Auditor](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/CodeAuditor/)

Personally, I prefer the CodeIt.Right rule authoring mechanism, so I would favour it if considerable custom rule development were planned.  However, if you just want to use out-of-the box rules, Code Auditor ships with quite a few more code style rules than CodeIt.Right, most of whose built-in rules target the compiled IL (like FxCop).

Comment: CodeIt.Right actually targets source code not the compiled IL (unlike FxCop)

Comment: @Serge: Apologies.  My Reflector spelunking did not go deep enough -- I pretty much stopped once I saw how few rules dealt with "raw" code style.  Something I saw at the time made me think that the rules that resemble FxCop rules were based on an IL-inspecting engine, but I can't imagine what that might have been now that I've revisited the relevant assemblies...

Answer (score 6):

The only ones I know of are:

[Microsoft's FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Of course, this only operates on compiled assemblies, so doesn't give the same functionality as StyleCop, and certainly won't help with things like naming schemes.

However, the closest thing is:

[Aivosto's Project Analyzer v9.0 for Visual Basic, VB.NET and VBA](http://www.aivosto.com/project/project.html)

The full version is not free, but this is the closest thing to StyleCop for VB.NET that I can find.

There have been a number of calls for a VB.NET version of Microsoft's StyleCop, such as those in [this thread](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=383) on the code.msdn.microsoft.com site.  That same thread also gives some good insight into why a VB.NET version doesn't exist.

Comment: FxCop does help with naming, but not things like how many spaces are used on each side of a "="

Answer (score 2):

I use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) on a daily basis and I find it fine for both code formatting and for solving naming issues. It allows to configure how naming must be enforced, how issues are displayed (hint, suggestion, warning, etc) and provides a precise code formatter (space, paranthesis, line breaks, this qualifier, etc).

Note that I don't know if it can be run in batch mode.

Comment: I found ReSharper runs too slowly when writing VB.NET to be useful

Answer (score 1):

Turning Option Explicit on by default is always a great idea and should be standard practice. I would argue it should be turned on by default in VS out of the box. But it doesn't come close to enforcing the out of the box rules that StyleCop does for C#, nor does it allow for you to create your own rules.

The whole reason for StyleCop's existence is because FxCop only works on compiled assemblies, leaving web projects out in the cold for a similar tool. With StyleCop, web developers get the same great rule enforcement and tight VS integration. It is a great tool for any C# developer.

It is unfortunate that it is only C# capable, a VB version would satisfy a large community that is left wanting something similar.

Comment: The analysis which StyleCop provides is *very* different from FxCop. StyleCop cheifly analyses cosmetic source code style whereas FxCop inspects the source code tree to see if you are doing bad things like calling virtual methods from within constructors. Both are very useful in their own right.

Answer (score 0):

There already is a very good style tool built into the VB compiler.  It is called Option Explicit On, put it at the top of the source code file or use Tools + Options + Project and Solutions + VB Defaults, Option Explicit = On.  If that wasn't turned on previously there could be a mountain of errors when you compile your code after changing that.

If it is clean or already turned on, consider that you are 95% close to writing clean C# code and that the language doesn't really matter anymore.

Comment: Option Explicit does not inforce nameing conventions, or all shared members must be accessed as “className.fieldName”