# VS coding conventions tools

Tags: visual-studio-2008, coding-style

Please can you help me to find some tools which will help developers to follow coding conventions for .NET( .NET Naming Guidelines,...)
I found this ones:

[StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis)

FxCop

Comment: and we develop primary in VB.NET

Comment: Then StyleCop is out of the picture, since it's for C# only. Have a look at this related SO question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131350/what-stylecop-like-tools-are-there-for-vb-net

Comment: I found http://submain.com/products/codeit.right.aspx , really great tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check [CodeIt.Right](http://submain.com/codeit.right) - it finds FxCop/StyleCop style violations and provides Auto Corrections for them, code metrics, reporting and more. Does both C# and VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got StyleCop and FxCop which are the main ones I've come across, you may be interested also in [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which helps by consistently formatting code and finding common errors.

There is also a [StyleCop for Resharper](http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/) plugin which shows StyleCop issues inline in the code and provides Quick Fixes for them.

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) can be used to perform static analysis on your compiled code and look for various rule violations, for example code violating architecte level boundaries or complexity limits.

Comment: Here's an useful article about using NDepend to check for coding conventions: http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/05/11/write-active-conventions-on-your-code-base.aspx